# How to return a single foaf:name?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have the following DBpedia SPARQL that shows philosophers that influenced philosophers. However, it returns duplicates when the philosopher has more than one `foaf:name`:

```
SELECT ?name ?influencedName
  WHERE {
  ?philosopher a dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
    dbpedia-owl:influenced ?influenced ;
    foaf:name ?name .
  ?influenced  a dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
    foaf:name ?influencedName .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++SELECT+%3Fname+%3FinfluencedName%0D%0A++++++WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Fphilosopher+a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A++++++++dbpedia-owl%3Ainfluenced+%3Finfluenced+%3B%0D%0A++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3Fname+.%0D%0A++++++%3Finfluenced++a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3FinfluencedName+.%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

How can I return a single name if there are multiple values for `?name` and `?includedName`.  I would be happy with the first one, or the least number of characters to pick which to keep.

Here is another example for just Plato influencing Bertrand Russell.  I would like this to return one row, but I get four:

```
SELECT ?name ?influencedName
  WHERE {
  ?philosopher a dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
    dbpedia-owl:influenced ?influenced ;
    foaf:name ?name , "Plato"@en .
  ?influenced  a dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
    foaf:name ?influencedName, "Bertrand Arthur William Russell, 3rd Earl Russell"@en .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++SELECT+%3Fname+%3FinfluencedName%0D%0A++++++WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Fphilosopher+a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A++++++++dbpedia-owl%3Ainfluenced+%3Finfluenced+%3B%0D%0A++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3Fname+%2C+%22Plato%22%40en+.%0D%0A++++++%3Finfluenced++a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3FinfluencedName%2C+%22Bertrand+Arthur+William+Russell%2C+3rd+Earl+Russell%22%40en+.%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Queries

It sounds like you want a query something like:

```
SELECT ?philosopher ?pName ?influence (SAMPLE(?iName) as ?iName)
WHERE {
  # This subquery selects all the philosophers and
  # selects just one of their names . 
  {
    SELECT ?philosopher (SAMPLE(?pName) as ?pName) WHERE {
      ?philosopher a dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
                   foaf:name ?pName .
    }
    GROUP BY ?philosopher
  }

  # This main query selects the influence of the 
  # philosophers and select their names.  The GROUP
  # BY on the outer query puts all the
  # (?philosopher,?pName,?influence,?iName) tuples 
  # that have the same ?philosopher, ?pName, and 
  # influence together, and the (SAMPLE(?iName) as ?iName)
  # in the outer SELECT combines them all, choosing an 
  # arbitrary representative ?iName.
  ?influence dbpedia-owl:influenced ?philosopher ;
             a dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
             foaf:name ?iName .
}
GROUP BY ?philosopher ?pName ?influence
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fphilosopher+%3FpName+%3Finfluence+%28SAMPLE%28%3FiName%29+as+%3FiName%29%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%23+This+subquery+selects+all+the+philosophers+and%0D%0A++%23+selects+just+one+of+their+names+.+%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A++++SELECT+%3Fphilosopher+%28SAMPLE%28%3FpName%29+as+%3FpName%29+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Fphilosopher+a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3FpName+.%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++GROUP+BY+%3Fphilosopher%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A++%23+This+main+query+selects+the+influence+of+the+%0D%0A++%23+philosophers+and+select+their+names.++The+GROUP%0D%0A++%23+BY+on+the+outer+query+puts+all+the%0D%0A++%23+%28%3Fphilosopher%2C%3FpName%2C%3Finfluence%2C%3FiName%29+tuples+%0D%0A++%23+that+have+the+same+%3Fphilosopher%2C+%3FpName%2C+and+%0D%0A++%23+influence+together%2C+and+the+%28SAMPLE%28%3FiName%29+as+%3FiName%29%0D%0A++%23+in+the+outer+SELECT+combines+them+all%2C+choosing+an+%0D%0A++%23+arbitrary+representative+%3FiName.%0D%0A++%3Finfluence+dbpedia-owl%3Ainfluenced+%3Fphilosopher+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3FiName+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Fphilosopher+%3FpName+%3Finfluence&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

If you are only interested in the names, and do not care about selecting the actual resources, you do not need `?philosopher` and `?influence` in the outermost `SELECT` and can make it

```
SELECT ?pName (SAMPLE(?iName) as ?iName)
WHERE { …
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3FpName+%28SAMPLE%28%3FiName%29+as+%3FiName%29%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A++++SELECT+%3Fphilosopher+%28SAMPLE%28%3FpName%29+as+%3FpName%29+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Fphilosopher+a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3FpName+.%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++GROUP+BY+%3Fphilosopher%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A++%3Finfluence+dbpedia-owl%3Ainfluenced+%3Fphilosopher+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3FiName+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Fphilosopher+%3FpName+%3Finfluence&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You also might want to add an `ORDER BY` at the end to make the results a little bit easier to check:

```
…
GROUP BY ?philosopher ?pName ?influence
ORDER BY ?pName
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3FpName+%28SAMPLE%28%3FiName%29+as+%3FiName%29%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A++++SELECT+%3Fphilosopher+%28SAMPLE%28%3FpName%29+as+%3FpName%29+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Fphilosopher+a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3FpName+.%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++GROUP+BY+%3Fphilosopher%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A++%3Finfluence+dbpedia-owl%3Ainfluenced+%3Fphilosopher+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++a+dbpedia-owl%3APhilosopher+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++foaf%3Aname+%3FiName+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Fphilosopher+%3FpName+%3Finfluence%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3FpName&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

These last results include, for Plato, the following rows:

```
"Plato"@en  "Socrates"@en
"Plato"@en  "Parmenides"@en
"Plato"@en  "Zeno of Elea"@en
"Plato"@en  "Pythagoras"@en
"Plato"@en  "Gorgias"@en
"Plato"@en  "Protagoras"@en
"Plato"@en  "Heraclitus"@en
```

In the query I've written here, I've used [`SAMPLE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#defn_aggSample) to pick one of the `foaf:name`s of a philosopher arbitrarily, but there are other functions in the [aggregate algebra](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#aggregateAlgebra) that you can use to select a value.  [Min](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#defn_aggMin) might be interest to you if you want the ‘first‘ value in order.

### Subqueries, GROUP BY, and SAMPLE, MIN, etc.

This is actually very similar to the example given for subqueries in [Section 12, Subqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#subqueries) of the SPARQL specification.  In that example, the following query is used to select the people that Alice knows, and for each one, select just one of the names of the people:

```
PREFIX : <http://people.example/>
SELECT ?y ?minName
WHERE {
  :alice :knows ?y .
  {
    SELECT ?y (MIN(?name) AS ?minName)
    WHERE {
      ?y :name ?name .
    } GROUP BY ?y
  }
}
```

This was not to hard to adapt for the philosophical influence problem.  The philosophers problem began by selecting all the philosophers and their names, grouping by the actual philosopher resource, and picking a representative name for each philosopher using sample.  The outer query does the same, but rather than selecting philosophers, it is selecting the entities that influenced each philosopher.  The results are grouped and a representative name for the influence is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I had issues with the query, the current issue being that is doesn't return anything.  I had to change the alias as I was getting errors with Duplicate variable names  Today is my 4th day with Sparql, I didn't know that subqueries were supported.  I will keep working on the query and report back

Comment: My problem for returning data was that I was using the wrong dbpedia-owl PREFIX.  The correct one is: PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>  I realize now that I must have the same name returned for the same philosopher for both subject and predicate so sample will not work.  I will figure out how to determine the one true name for the philosopher and see if I can adapt it.  I marked this as the answer since it does answer the question as stated.

Comment: Not enough room in comments for my findings so "answering my question"

Answer (score 1):

I have determined how I want to select the unique name for a philosopher, see sparql below that returns one name for each philosopher.

However, I don't see a why to incorporate this in the larger query that returns a name both for philosopher and for influenced philosopher without running this code once for each philosopher which would be a large and unwieldy query.  My sense is that my code will be more readable if I run the philosopher names and the influensed by queries separatly and look up the names in code rather than sparql.  Perhaps I am missing some sparql feature that will make this easy.  Please Advice

Here is the description of how I am getting unique names:

Get all names for a Philosopher from foaf:names and dbprop:names
Filter to include only names that contain at least one Latin letter character ( A-Z )
Find the length of the shortest names
Pick the minimum of all of the names that are shortest

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?philosopher (min(?name) as ?minName)
WHERE {{
   ?philosopher foaf:name ?name        .
  } UNION {
   ?philosopher dbpprop:name ?name     .
  }
  FILTER( strlen(?name) = ?minLength )   .  # get the shortest names
  FILTER( REGEX( str(?name) , "[A-Z]" )) .  # exlude names with no latin charachters
  {
    SELECT ?philosopher (min(strlen(?name)) as ?minLength)
    WHERE {{
      ?philosopher a  dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
         foaf:name ?name .
    } UNION {
      ?philosopher a  dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
         dbpprop:name ?name .
    }
    FILTER( REGEX( str(?name) , "[A-Z]" )) .
    }
    GROUP BY ?philosopher
  }
}
GROUP BY ?philosopher
ORDER BY ?philosopher
```